# Is there a reason to avoid unix style relative paths in python?

Tags: python, path

I have written this:

```
ancestor_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *([os.pardir]*5 + [ancestor_name]))
```

I'm thinking, why don't I just say

```
ancestor_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../../../", ancestor_name]))
```

It seems to work in Windows and linux and is a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Arguably, the [os.pardir]*5 is easier to read than counting five "../" in terms of knowing how far up it went ... but that doesn't seem very persuasive: subjective at best.  I'm looking for a more concrete "absolute" reason.

Comment: Are you bothered about Windows compatibility? If you know that you will only ever run on Linux or OSX then carry on using the UNIX representation.

Comment: @SalimFadhley as I said in the question, '../..' appears to work in python under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `".."` instead of `os.pardir` not an issue unless you want to maintain compatibility with the *classic Mac OS* ( predecessor of OS X ) in which

1. Parent directory is denoted by `::`
2. Directory separator is denoted by `:`
3. Current directory is also denoted by `:`

You can check this by

```
import macpath

print(macpath.pardir) #print parent dir
print(macpath.curdir) #print current dir
print(macpath.sep) #print dir separator
```

The `os` module imports `pardir` from `os.path` module.
Importing `macpath` imports `os.path` of classic Mac OS in other operating systems. Similarly `ntpath` is for Windows and `posixpath` for POSIX systems.

Using `os.pardir` is also useful to maintain readability of the code.

**Note**: using "../../../../../" is a bad idea in windows because here the directory separator is hard coded too and windows uses "\" as default directory separator (os.sep) . This directory separator is used by `os.path.join()`. So the resulting path will look hideous with mixed slashes. *There is no compelling reason to stop you from using it* and of course mixed slashes can be corrected with `os.path.normpath()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.pardir` makes the code portable to non-POSIX systems. If compatibility isn't an issue, then it doesn't matter much. But one could argue that using `os.pardir` can be more readable; but that's too subjective to quantify.

Comment: Sorry for the very basic question: what is a "non posix" system where python would not get this right:  ancestor_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../../../", ancestor_name]))  ?

Comment: Windows, for example, uses `\` instead of `/`. POSIX are *nix systems, basically. If a system is non-POSIX, there's no guarantee that `../` represents the parent directory. So if this is for a project you want to run on literally anything, avoid using literal paths.

Comment: I _thought_ this was the explanation, before I asked the question.  I was prompted to ask the question when I discovered that this _does_ work on Windows.  For example, on Windows, os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../..')) is True.   This left me wondering whether this is reliably going to work or ... what?